# uninitialized constant AFMotion::HTTP::AFFormURLParameterEncoding (NameError)

Tags: afnetworking, rubymotion

Recently afmotion start to rise error below, even for simple request

```
$ rake
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.1-Development
     Build vendor/Pods
  Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.1-Development/Network.app
(main)> AFMotion::HTTP.get("http://google.com") do |result|
(main)>     p result.body
(main)> end
2013-05-21 18:29:00.904 Network[75552:11303] http.rb:37:in `parameter_encoding': uninitialized constant AFMotion::HTTP::AFFormURLParameterEncoding (NameError)
  from http.rb:14:in `block in included:'
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant AFMotion::HTTP::AFFormURLParameterEncoding>
```

This code works several weeks ago.
Does anyone have same issue, and know how to solve this?

My version settings are below:

```
ruby version: 2.0.0-p195 (1.9.3-p194 also fails)
rubymotion version: 2.0
afmotion version: 0.4
AFNetworking version: 1.2.1
```

Comment: Does it work if you set `app.detect_dependencies = false` in your Rakefile? If so, submit a RubyMotion support request.

Comment: Still does not work... Where can I submit the request?

Comment: Just run `motion support` at the command line.